# Staring tomcat in netbeans issue

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

The issue is I'm trying to run Tomcat from Netbeans. In logs I can see that Tomcat is started up (in xxx milliseconds), but Netbeans doesn't receive information about that and It's thinking that Tomcat is not started. The problem appears on Mac.

Netbeans 11.3
Tomcat 9.0.33

I used to change "use proxy", but it didn't help. Reinstalling of all these doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks very similar to the issue reported in NetBeans Bug Report [NETBEANS-3903 Netbeans 11.2 fails to detect successful startup of Tomcat 9.0.31](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3903), which summarized the steps to reproduce as follows:

> Exact steps
>
> 1. Add tomcat server
> 2. Run tomcat server,
> 3. Confirm it starts (browser success and console logs success),
> 4. Minutes later error appears to say "Starting of Tomcat Failed"

The issue is not resolved in NetBeans 11.3, but will be fixed in NetBeans 12.0. In the meantime, the only workaround I can think of is to run Tomcat externally (i.e. outside of NetBeans), and deploy your NetBeans projects to Tomcat manually.

If your problem is different to that described in the bug report, update your question to explain how it differs.